# Excel VBA If Not Sheet is Sheet 1 or sheet 2 and Boolean is true within a For Next loop

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

The entire macro pulls data from a database and updates the sheets in excel I am basically trying to tell it to update everything except the two specific sheets one at the end and one at the beginning. The code has been in use for a while but I want to add a sheet to the beginning and cannot get it to work.

Here is the code in question

```
For Each wsSheet In wbBook.Worksheets
    strName = wsSheet.Name
    If Not (wsSheet Is (Sheet1)) And _
       (blnTF Or (strName = wsActSheet.Name)) _
       Then ... other code
```

This above code works fine but i am trying to add an Or statement to check if not Sheet 1 or Sheet 2.

I am new to VBA and unfamiliar with the syntax i know logically what i want to do and have tried multiple times

this is what I tried as well

```
For Each wsSheet In p_wbBook.Worksheets
    strName = wsSheet.Name
    If Not (wsSheet Is (Sheet1) Or (Sheet2)) And _
       (blnTF Or (strName = wsActSheet.Name)) _
       Then .... other code
```

but it doesnt like the or statement I also tried this outside the if not by writing

```
If wsSheet is Sheet2 Then
Goto Next
```

but it did not like that either.

Any help on why Excel does not like this syntax would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't compount your statement in that way. It would have to be "If Not (wsSheet Is (Sheet1) or wsSheet Is (Sheet2)) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PAH is correct.  You have to have a complete statement after the OR in this context.

```
(condition 1) Or (condition 2)
```

---

Change to:

```
If Not (wsSheet Is (Sheet1) Or wsSheet Is (Sheet2)) And _
```

---

For testing purposes I used the following:

```
For Each wsSheet In wbBook.Worksheets
    strName = wsSheet.Name
    If Not (strName = "Sheet1" Or strName = "Sheet2") And (blnTF Or (strName = wsActSheet.Name)) Then
        MsgBox (strName)
    End If
Next wsSheet
```